# Using 'or' when checking against URLS in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following to do something if the specified URL matches that of the current page:

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("collections/all/colourful") > -1) {
```

I have a whole bunch of these as I cant seem to specify a list of URLs to apply the function to. I would like to give a list of 10-40 urls to apply it to. I tried (using two URLs as an example):

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("collections/all/colourful") || ("collections/all/notcolourful") > -1) {
```

and

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("collections/all/colourful" || "collections/all/notcolourful") > -1) {
```

but neither seems to work.

Sorry if this is basic, but I looked and couldn't find an answer anywhere. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I see what you're trying to do, and it would be a kind of nice syntax.  That isn't how logical `or` works, though.  Open a JavaScript console and paste in `"collections/all/colourful" || "collections/all/notcolourful"` to get an idea of what's actually happening.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will be less verbose and cleaner if your list of urls is long:

```
var arrOfUrls = [url1, url2, url3]; //replace these with your url strings

var atLeastOneMatches = arrOfUrls.some(function(url) {
  return window.location.href.indexOf(url > -1);
});

if (atLeastOneMatches) {
  //do stuff here
}
```

Comment: Surprised this wasn't +1'd considering it scales better so...+1

Comment: Plus I just noticed Stu Ungar as your profile picture, I'd upvote again just for that if possible :D

Comment: @Zenith, lol, thanks.  You are officially the first to notice (or at least comment on it), so much <3

Answer (score 2):

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("collections/all/colourful") > -1 || window.location.href.indexOf("collections/all/notcolourful") > -1) {
```

You can't compare like you were trying to... Basically, you were saying `if(window.location... OR true)` before.

Comment: I have seen some other answers given, but this was straightforward enough for me, and was exactly what I wanted. Thanks again.

Comment: @ripsnorter While this is straightforward enough for you, it's really only clean for 2 comparisons. If you end up implementing up to 40, it will be a mess unless a different solution is used to store them in an array and loop over them.

Comment: @Ian. Okay, I changed my answer to one that scales better. While this answer was good enough for me, I suppose it will serve the community better if my chosen answer is the scalable, better solution. Thanks.

Comment: @ripsnorter I would agree, you should be using the more *scalable* version... For that matter, you could just pass an array of urls through a function that is almost exactly the same as this one. Enjoy programming :)

Comment: @ripsnorter I mean, this answer definitely answer your immediate question and provides the correct logic. I just wanted to point out it's best for a few comparisons, not 40 :)

Answer (score 2):

With only one expression:

```
/collections\/all\/(not)colourful/.test( window.location.href )
```

Comment: Except that the string they're testing doesn't start with "/" (just saying)

Comment: @Jonah Then you can put all the patterns into an array (like the other solutions) and use `new RegExp(arr.join("|"), "g").test(window.location.href)` or something :)

Comment: @Ian, At that point, why are you using the patterns?  Unless there is a huge savings in the sense that you only have a handful of patterns to generate 40 urls, I think using regex's here is an unnecessary complication, albeit a small one.

Comment: @Jonah I'm just trying to explain how it could be used. I'm not saying it's any better/worse than the other solutions with `indexOf`.

Comment: @Jonah Trust me, I really like your solution with `.some()` - too often do I forget these "special" array methods, especially when they are perfect for a situation like this. Unfortunately, I have exhausted my votes for the day, otherwise you'd have a vote from me :)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for this:

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("collections/all/colourful") > -1 || 
    window.location.href.indexOf("collections/all/notcolourful") > -1) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("collections/all/colourful") > -1 || window.location.href.indexOf("collections/all/notcolourful") > -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply go through a list (array) until you find one:

```
var found = false;

for (var x = 0; x < listOfUrls.length; x ++){
  if(window.location.href.indexOf(listOfUrls[x] > -1) {
     found=true;
     break;
  }
}

if(found){//do something
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to repeat the entire command when using the or statement.

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("collections/all/colourful") > -1 || window.location.href.indexOf("collections/all/notcolourful") > -1)
```